# linsolve derivative

Tags: matrix-equations, linear-algebra

Consider a vector $\mathbf{g} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and a matrix $\mathbf{A} \equiv \mathbf{A(g)} \in \mathcal{M}_{p\times q} \[\mathbb{R}\]$, a function of $\mathbf{g}$.

Furthermore, let $\mathbf{S} \in \mathcal{M}_{p \times r} \[\mathbb{R}\]$, independent of $\mathbf{g}$.

Is it a way to calculate $\displaystyle \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{S})}{\partial g_i}$, where $L(\cdot)$ is the `linsolve` Matlab function?

One can suppose that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial g_i}$ is known.

Comment: Try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
This site is for research maths questions and probably you will not get an answer here.

Comment: I think that the question is relevant here instead, but please edit the question and give us a real mathematical description of what `linsolve` does. Please do some work and read the Matlab documentation for us. :) I guess it is simply `A^{+}S` (Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse)?

Comment: Kinda solved on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/derivative-of-linsolve